# About which topic is this text talking? a ticket for a train, bus?

Tags: meaning

> A: 席は、1階と2階とどちらがよろしいでしょうか。
> B: 1階の前の方の席をお願いします。
> A: あいにく前の方はもういっぱいなんですが。
> B: じゃ、後ろの方でもかまいません。  ([source, page 2, number 2](https://www.docdroid.net/gMfeMMP/img-20170823-0002-new.pdf))

In this text, they are talking about a ticket for a train, bus or something the like? The 1かいの前の方の席 suggests to me that the ticket is for public transport. 前の方 means "facing in the direction of travel" in this context, am I right?

Since this text seems to make every effort not to be too specific about what these 2 are talking exactly, I merely wanted to ask for confirmation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

前の方の席 refers to seats near the front-row, the stage, the screen, etc.

I think most people feel they are talking about a ticket for some stage performance, since they are talking about 1階 and 2階 ("the first/second floor"). Balcony seats are often referred to as 2階席 in Japanese. They may be talking about a bilevel/double-decker train/bus, but asking for a 前の方の席 of a train doesn't make much sense to me.